# Deploy a spring boot rest application with google cloud

Tags: google-app-engine, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform

I trying so much to deploy a spring boot application on google cloud app engine, after so many documents here im.
when i try to deploy a simple spring boot application like the exemples its works but with my app the deploy process take a long time and i got 502 error. looking at app engine logs my application keep on infinit reboot loop.
my app.yaml :

`runtime: custom
env: flex`

My docker file:

`FROM gcr.io/google_appengine/openjdk
VOLUME /tmp
ADD vaptuber-jjaerp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar
CMD [ "java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/app.jar"]`

and here is the app log:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1gG3dVgi0WoTzM2RXlaQjJka0E/view?usp=sharing
I has deployed a fat jar to test, in local machine works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Cloud GCP was just recently announced. It should help to better integrate your Spring application with GCP. Take a look at the following resources.

- [Announcing Spring Cloud GCP](https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2018/02/announcing-Spring-Cloud-GCP-integrating-your-favorite-Java-framework-with-Google-Cloud.html)
- [Spring Cloud GCP](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-gcp/)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your application is running out of memory and being killed and restarted by the `OOM` Killer. The solution is as simple as increasing the memory on the App Engine `VM`. See my answer here:

> [Deploy a SpringBoot / Angular 4 on Google App Engine with maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47830477/deploy-a-springboot-angular-4-on-google-app-engine-with-maven/48774859#48774859)